# Sort Algorithm - find which chart bar sees different bar

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm having difficulty trying to find an algorithm with **O(n)** runtine efficiency.

Provided with array in size n, array contains integers, for example.
 I have to know which array cell (can imagine as chart bar) is looking on which cell.

Formally: `lookingAtIndex(i) = max { -1} U {j | arr[j] > arr[i], j<i}`, where `-1` stands for y axis.

**Edit**: what is the first bar that is higher than the current bar where im at. If there isn't one, its Y axis
Example, provided with array : 7,3,5,2,1,9..

Then 7 is looking on y axis, 3 is looking at 7, 5 is looking at 7, 2 on 5, 1 on 2 and 9 on y axis.

I'm kinda lost, everything I do I stay in O(nLogn). 
It's not a full sorting algorithm, thus it's possible to do it with O(n).
Printing the results its possible while running, no need to store information until the end.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean "looking at", please elaborate and preferably give a formal definition.

Comment: Meaning what is the first bar that is higher than the current bar where im at. If there isn't one, its Y axis.

Comment: Got it, added a formal definition to your question. Also note that the claim `It's not a full sorting algorithm, thus it's possible to do it with O(n)` is not true, for example element distinctness problem under the algebraic tree computation model.

Comment: @amit true, but i ment for this specific question, it applies.

Comment: what kind of sorting do you want to achieve?

Comment: Using your definition of `lookingAtIndex`, shouldn't 2 be looking at 7 ?

Comment: @Othman No, because index of 5 is higher than index of 7, so max{-1,0,1,2} = 2, which is the index of 5.

Comment: @Othman, its not true, the first bar that is higher from him is 5

Comment: No i was wrong, amit is right

Comment: @Onheiron its sorting the chart bars as i was saying, mind that its not sorting the numbers by how big each one is.

Comment: so you want a O(n) algorithm to find out which bar every bar is "looking at"?

Comment: Correct, that is what im looking for

Comment: I thought about using a stack wheras im atoring the charts by size there and poping them until i get to a higher value and if its empty, its Y axis, problem is: im thinking i exeeds the O(n)

Comment: @OriRefael, your current algorithm to find the bar for an one index is O(?)

Comment: NlogN, but its wrong. Have bugs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with a simple stack.

```
Compare each element a[i] with the top of the stack T
while ( T <= a[i] ) 
   pop T
if the stack is empty
   a[i] is looking at the y-axis
else
   a[i] is looking at T
push a[i] onto the stack
```

For example, using the array [7,3,5,2,1,9]

```
a[0]=7 T=empty     7 is looking at y-axis
a[1]=3 T=7         3 is looking at 7
a[2]=5 T=3 pop 3
       T=7         5 is looking at 7
a[3]=2 T=5         2 is looking at 5
a[4]=1 T=2         1 is looking at 2
a[5]=9 T=1 pop 1
       T=2 pop 2
       T=5 pop 5
       T=7 pop 7
       T=empty     9 is looking at y-axis
```

Note that every number gets pushed onto the stack, and each number can only be popped once from the stack, so the number of stack operations is at most 2N, and the whole algorithm is O(n).

Comment: this is not O(n), imagine you have this example 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9 : to find the bar for 9 it will cost you to go through all the stack, which will contain all the elements

Comment: Yes, you push 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1. Then you pop 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. That's N-1 push operations, and N-1 pop operations. So O(n).

Comment: @Othman: you didn't read carefully enough the justification of the O(N) behavior.

Comment: Where im poping the item to? Am i not loaing it after the pop()s? Also, if im poping 1,2,3,4,5,6,..n-1 times, isnt it jast went n^2?

Comment: Yes O(n) for retrieving the bar for 9, I think he asked a O(n) algorithm for retrieving the bars of all the indexes

Comment: @OriRefael  Popping just means take the number off the top of the stack and throw it away. Once a number has been popped, it is never needed again.

Comment: @Othman Once a number has been popped it is never needed again, so each number gets popped only once. In your example, they all get popped at the end, but it doesn't matter when they get popped. It only matters that each number only gets pushed once, and popped once.

Comment: I thought he needed a O(n) algorithm for all the array, not one index

Comment: @Othman Not sure how I can explain it any better. Try to find an example array that is not O(n).

Comment: So basically im storing the highest value and decendeing. Thats the general thought?

Comment: @OriRefael Yes, the stack will have the largest value seen so far, followed by additional, strictly decreasing values.

Comment: Thanks, that will probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

I head up with a linear solution, with a large factor ahead. So I think it may not be the best solution.

Here is the thing. Let call the input array of integers `I`, of length `n`. Let be `M` the greatest number in `I`, found in `O(n)`. I assume first that the min value in `I` is 0; if not, substracting the min value does not change the solution, and `M` is in the general case `max(I)-min(I)`.

Create an array `T` of length `m`, with all elements set at -1. This array is the storage of the indexes of the "looked at" bar for every possible integer in `I`; initialization is -1, index of a virtual left-most bar.

Create also the array `S` being the output array o the indexes of the "looked-at" bars.

Now, for each element `e` in `I` with index `i` in the array, it looks at the bar whose index is precisely `T[e]`. So `S[i] = T[e]`. Then set all elements `T[0..e]` with the value `i`.

At the end of the loop, `S` is filled with the indexes of the "looked-at" bars; it's easy to get back the value of these bars.

As you can see, the over-all complexity is `O(M*n)`, so the complexity is linear with the length of `I`. It's may be not very efficient due to the factor `M` as I said before (any improvement is welcomed).

**EDIT**

Prefer the solution of [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29766524/1507014), mine is awkward in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have an array that finishes with : ... A - B,

and lookingAtIndex(A) = X, and let's find the result for B :
 if A > B then it's A, else all the indexes between A and lookingAtIndex(A) can't be a good answer since they are less than A,
 if lookingAtIndex(A) > B then it's the answer else look at lookingAtIndex(lookingAtIndex(A)) etc...

But you'll need a way to store the bars of each index, I think the idea of the stack gived by user3386109 is a very good implementation, and you'll only need to store the values needed